# Javascript is not "opening" url's

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what's wrong with this script. It "should" work.

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" onclick="goTo('img1');">
```

Javascript

```
function goTo(img) {
        if( img === 'img1' ) { window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank'); }
        else if( img === 'img2' ) { window.open('https://www.yahoo.com/','_blank'); }
        etc...
        else{ alert("This image is not recognized: " + img ); }
    }
```

[JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/xuzc70gn/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/xuzc70gn/2/)

---

**Edit: On the website, I have the javascript code inside a .ready(), like so:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

function goTo(img) {
    if( img === 'ivory' ) { window.open('https://www.indiegogo.com/project/preview/a0d4cff9','_blank'); }
    else{ alert("This image is not recognized: " + img ); }
}

...more functions...
});
```

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all? Just wrap the relevant images with an anchor tag...

Comment: Because they are inside a slider that will break if I add hyperlinks

Comment: You do realise some search crawlers don't register Javascript `onclick` attributes as links? Just to be on the safe side, use an `anchor` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `goTo` function outside of `.ready()` event like following:

```
function goTo(img) {
    if( img === 'ivory' ) { window.open('https://www.indiegogo.com/project/preview/a0d4cff9','_blank'); }
    else{ alert("This image is not recognized: " + img ); }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    ...more functions...


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your goto function is not declared in global scope, and thus cannot be found.
Try:

```
window.goTo = function (img) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, JsFiddle runs your code on page load. In other words, it wraps your `goTo()` function in anther function, like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    function goTo(img) {
        if( img === 'img1' ) {
            window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank');
        }
        else if( img === 'img2' ) {
            window.open('https://www.yahoo.com/','_blank');
        }
        else {
            alert("This image is not recognized: " + img );
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it inaccessible from, for example, an `onclick` attribute in HTML.

To fix this, you need to change the Load type setting to "No wrap - in <body>":

[image]

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuzc70gn/3/)

Comment: I am using jsfiddle to `"illustrate"` what I am going through in a real page

Comment: then you haven't provided enough information. Your code works perfectly by only changing JsFiddle settings